# React Native, calling on functions

Tags: json, react-native

I have a function in react native

```
 _onPressButtonGET: function() {
    fetch("https://newsapi.org/v1/articles?source=techcrunch&apiKey=[YOUR_API_KEY]", {method: "GET"})
    .then((response) => response.json())
    .then((responseData) => {
//             AlertIOS.alert(
//                  "Latest Story: TechCrunch",
//                 "" + responseData.articles[0].title
//             )
responseData.articles[0].title
    })
    .done();
},
```

and I'm trying to get the article title in a  component but am having trouble doing so. How can I do that? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First you will need to define a state, which will store your title. You can do it with a class property:

```
class TitleExample extends Component {

  state = { title: "" };

}
```

Then you will need to call your fetch function. You can do it in `componentWillMount` hence the data will be fetched before the component's mounting:

```
class TitleExample extends Component {

  state = { title: "" };

  componentWillMount() {
    fetch("https://newsapi.org/v1/articles?source=techcrunch&apiKey=[YOUR_API_KEY]")
    .then((response) => response.json())
    .then((responseData) => this.setState({ title: responseData.articles[0].title }));
  }

}
```

And finally you can render your title:

```
class TitleExample extends Component {

  state = { title: "" };

  componentWillMount() {
    fetch("https://newsapi.org/v1/articles?source=techcrunch&apiKey=[YOUR_API_KEY]")
    .then((response) => response.json())
    .then((responseData) => this.setState({ title: responseData.articles[0].title }));
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <View>
        <Text>{this.state.title}</Text>
      </View>
    );
  }

}
```

You are doing something very basic, not related to React Native particularly so I recommend you to read the [state docs](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html) on the React website.

EDIT:

I you want to render all articles, you can store all of them in the state then loop through in the render:

```
class TitleExample extends Component {

  state = { articles: [] };

  componentWillMount() {
    fetch("https://newsapi.org/v1/articles?source=techcrunch&apiKey=[YOUR_API_KEY]")
    .then((response) => response.json())
    .then((responseData) => this.setState({ articles: responseData.articles }));
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <View>
        {this.state.articles.map(article => (
          <Text>{article.title}</Text>
        ))}
      </View>
    );
  }

}
```

Comment: Ok thank you!! @Kerumen then how would I be able to loop through all of the items in the JSON instead of just calling on the first one, is there like a .each or something?